# Will documents folder be deleted when I delete application?

Tags: ios

I have an app. Each app has documents folder. Will documents folder be deleted when I delete(uninstall) application?

Comment: Is this a programming question or a general question about using iOS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes the documents folder will be deleted since you uninstall the app. But if you have iCloud enabled it will backup the contents of the Documents directory. Read more at https://developer.apple.com/icloud/documentation/data-storage/

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the entire sandbox (including Documents) will be deleted.